# Venn Diagram symmetric difference

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> Draw the Venn Diagram for $C \backslash (A \oplus B)$

#### Attempt at solution

From what I understand the symmetric difference between $A$ and $B$ is the region of everything outside the shared region between the two spheres, which includes the $C$ region. But then $C \backslash$ that region means everything that's in $C$ except that region defined previously (which included $C$), so that would mean the big region of $C$ is not greyed out ? I guess I'm just confused by this.

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Can anyone confirm my solution ?

Comment: If I read it correctly this should be the area only in $C$ together with the area shared by $A,B,C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misinterpreting what the [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) $A \oplus B$ is: it's all the points that are in exactly one of $A$ or $B$, but not both. In particular, this means that the "exclusively $C$" region is *not* included in $A \oplus B$, because elements exclusively in $C$ are in neither $A$ nor $B$.

Based on this, to fix your diagram you also need to shade the exclusively $C$ region.